# nosuchmethod error but method exists when i use provided in android

Tags: android

I have a module A it has a function

```
public boolean a () {
   ...
}
```

and then I provided module A in module B and use a() such as

```
public void b () {
   a()
}
```

and then I compile A and B in module C, in module C

```
 public void c()  {


   b()

 }
```

and its build successful.

but when I change a() returned value in module A, such as

```
public String a() {
}
```

and when I run module c, it occurs a problem nosuchmethoderror(no virtual method a()Z)

but when I rebuild module B and module C, it works successfully.

So how did provided worked?

Comment: post the module c code too

Comment: this both not in one project ,i exported module A & B as aar .

Answer (score 0):

Only static functions we can call in this way:

```
  A.a()
```

So please declare

```
  public static boolean a () {
      ...
  }
```

Good luck

Comment: this is  not inportant ,just for example,thsi real question is returned value ,

Comment: have you added dependencies in the modules B and C like :
     implementation project(path: ':lib') <- this for module A  and   implementation project(path: ':lib2')  <- this for module B ?

Comment: module B :  provided 'A'     module C  : compile 'A' compile 'B'

Comment: please open Run/Debug Configurations dialog (Run -> Edit Configurations on the main menu) and check the Before lunch section of the project -> there should be an entry like "Gradle aware Make" or "Build"

Comment: i could not found it

Comment: in fact  i changed the returned value in module A function a ,but i am not rebuild module B and post new version of module B , just rebuild module C, and it run failed happend in function b();

Comment: Are you using Android studio?

Comment: I do not noticed "this both not in one project ,i exported module A & B as aar", so we should rebuild them separately if they are outside of the project